# Sorting List Given a specific scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, sorting, c#-4.0

I have a List of objects that I need to sort based on two columns:

```
List<Customers> customers = CustomerService.GetAll();
```

Now, the existing code is as follows:

```
customers.Sort(new CustomerComparer(sortColumn));
```

where Sort Column could be Date, Name, Amount, Description.

In the comparer class I have:

```
public class CustomerComparer : IComparer<Customer>
{
    public CustomerComparer(string expression){}

    public int Compare(Customer c, Customer d)
    {
        int value = 0;
        switch(expression)
        {
            case "Name":
            value = String.Compare(c.Name, d.Name,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            break;
            case "Date":
            value = DateTime.Compare(b.Date, d.Date);
            break;
            case "Description":
            value = String.Compare(c.Name, d.Name,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            break;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Given this scenario, how can I sort based on two Columns? for instance I should always be able to sort on any of those columns, but then BY Date always like:

```
DESCRIPTION ,DATE
NAME, DATE
```

etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ditching the CustomComparer and using Linq? It then becomes trivial to order by multiple columns.

```
var orderedList = 
      customers.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ThenByDescending(c => c.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: I wonder why when I type OrderBy it does not come up, it says: System.Collections.Generic.List<Customer> does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a firt argument of type'System.Collections.Generic.List<Customer> could be found. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: I am on asp.net 4.0 by the way

Comment: Got it, needed to add Using linq